# mailto function in AS3 not fully working on android tablet

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, email

I created a small SWF game with AS3 with a small form at the end to capture the users' details and send with a mailto function. It works perfectly on the desktop but when I tested it on the tablet - the mailto function works except that it does not include the details that the user entered in the form. I have tried using different mail apps and different SWF players but to no avail.

Here is my script for the form page

```
submit_BTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, openEmail);
    function openEmail(e:Event):void{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:" + "thisemailaddressleftout" + 
    "?subject="+"thissubjectleftout"+ "&body=" + name2_field.text + "\n" + 
    cell2_field.text + "\n" + email2_field.text));
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Thank you");
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am a junior in flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that the URLRequest string must be a valid URL encoded string, so no spaces or special characters.

Perform an initial test with no variables, so try something like:

```
function openEmail(e:Event):void{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:name@domain.com?subject=Test&body=Hello"));
gotoAndPlay(1, "Thank you");
}
```

If that works you know you're on the right track.

If that does work you can encode your variables with encodeURIComponent();

[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will keep this in mind in further scripting adventures - I managed to get it working with another SWF player herewith the link if someone else should have a similar problem with finding an SWF player for android that works decently; https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.coolcode.utils.swfviewer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm9yZy5jb29sY29kZS51dGlscy5zd2Z2aWV3ZXIiXQ.. Further still, thank you for the support